# Empty div and reappend content strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this board where I append some boxes in a random order.

When click the button I want to append the boxes in a new random order but apparently doesnt work (.board remains empty)

http://jsbin.com/pedanobawe/2/edit?html,js,output

```
makeBoard();

$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('.board').empty();
  makeBoard();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is that by passing an array to a function, you don't make a copy but just pass the reference. Your `tiles` is being emptied, and therefor you can't reuse it.

I've updated your jsbin to make a copy of the array before manipulating it:
`tilesCopy = tiles.splice();`

See http://jsbin.com/wirekimuva/2/edit for a working example.